# Картинка вместо названия

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Не подскажите, вот у меня есть сайт, и я хотел бы вместо названия скачать с `Letebit`, установить, картинку "Letebit" ссылкой на мои файлы. Как это сделать? Я по всему интернету искал html код картинки с Letebit с возможностью добавлять свои ссылки, но так и не нашел! Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="ссылка на ваш файл" target="_blank"><img src="ссылка на вашу картинку" /></a>
```

Извините, но зачем вам сайт? Делаем выводы...

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="ссылка"><img src="картинка" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="ссылка"><img src="http://letitbit.net/images/bg_logo.gif" alt="" /></a>
```